# How to measure for outlets above kitchen countertop?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, kitchens

I am redoing my kitchen and trying to make sure I get the electrical set correctly.
Had an electrician out to give me scope on some questions but didn't think to ask this one.

When looking online, I keep seeing that outlets should be 15"-20" above finished countertop.
But I cannot get a clear answer regarding if that's to Top, Center, or Bottom.
If I install at 15" to top, that puts my bottom roughly 11" from the counter - which would end up being wrong if it has to be 15" to bottom.

I'm also seeing LOTS of guys saying they rough in at 48" to top from subfloor.

- https://youtu.be/RYBIDAsqA8M?si=NlyXGu0ICerw2hx4&t=33
- https://www.electriciantalk.com/threads/standard-height-of-boxes-above-countertops.54426/

But with a cabinet & counter ending up 36" high, that doesn't land in the 15"-20" measurement in any direction.
Hoping someone can help clear up this one a little.
I'm in Utah if that has any bearing on what code is applicable.

Comment: The electriciantalk .com conversation is a hodgepodge of commercial kitchen (ie, no upper cabinets) and *switch* heights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some degree this is subjective/opinion/off-topic. The rules I know regarding receptacle *location* that I know of are:

- Maximum distance to a receptacle *horizontally* which is generally 2' on a kitchen counter (i.e., one every 4').
- Required receptacles can't be too high - not sure if that is 5' or 6' or what, but not a factor in this conversation.

Basically the kitchen receptacles have to be within easy reach from anywhere on the counter. They can even be pop-up receptacles *in* the counter. It really comes down to what actually works best in a particular kitchen.

Here are a few key things to consider:

- Countertop Height

Kitchen countertops are typically 36" above the floor. That's pretty much fixed because that fits standard cabinet sizes - i.e., to do anything different requires custom cabinets.

- Upper Cabinets

This is probably the most important thing. But the upper cabinet height can vary. According to [this article found in a Google search](https://cabinetstiles.com/how-high-upper-cabinets-should-be-from-your-floor-and-countertop/) typical height is 48" above the countertop, with 18" in between countertop and upper cabinet. It can be a little lower (easier to reach) but not too much lower in order to provide adequate work space for small appliances. It can be a little higher (more work space) but not too much higher in order to keep dishes and things within easy reach.

So that's the baseline - 18" to work with.

- Backsplash

I would allow 4" for a backsplash. You may not have one at all. Or it may be a little shorter than that. But I wouldn't place any electrical boxes lower than 40" (36" + 4")

Now you're down to 14" from top of backsplash to bottom of upper cabinet.

- Receptacle/Box Size

A standard box is about 4" tall. But the faceplate is a little larger, so I would allow a minimum of 5".

So that leaves 9" of free space (14" - 5" = 9"), which is either above the receptacle, below the receptacle or split.

In the end it is a bit subjective. But **not** 15" or 20" above the countertop - that will clearly be too high because of the upper cabinets. In fact, the article I linked suggests 15" - 20" as the range for the height of the upper cabinets!

48" is a nice round number. If you put the center of each box at 48" and have a 5" faceplate, then the bottom will be at 45.5", 11.5" above the countertop, ~ 7" - 8" above the backsplash, and the top will be at 50.5", 3.5" below the upper cabinets. A little higher or a little lower is fine.

Comment: The 48" to top of box from subfloor makes plent of sense from a standard perspective, but I keep gettin this recommend of 15-20 above counter that I can't make sense of. Maybe it's wrong since I'm realizing the sites that indicate it never cite code for it.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I think the 15" - 20" is a height for the upper cabinets, not for the receptacles which need to be in between.

Answer (score 3):

If speaking of standard cabinet heights, 15 to 20 inches above the counter top is too high. The bottom of the upper cabinets are around 18 inches from the countertop.

I usually mark the bottoms of the boxes at 44 inches.

Comment: 15-20 seems high to me as well, but I see it referenced in lots of places (but I'm realizing no where is it citing code).